# Squid limit the number of requests per minute for certain domains

Tags: squid

Is there a way of limiting my squid users to access let's say Facebook more than once per hour for example? I know how to deny domains but I want to limit this request size to 1/given time if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do that with Squid directly. You could try writing an external acl helper.